# New match feature

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

I downloaded Enterprise 2015 Preview 3. How do I make this program work under C#7?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

abstract class Animal { }
class Dog : Animal
{
    public string BarkLikeCrazy()
    {
        return "WOOF WOOF WOOF";
    }
}

class Cat : Animal { }
class Swan : Animal { }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var animals = new Animal[] { new Dog(), new Cat(), new Swan() };

        var organizedAnimals = from animal in animals
                               let sound = animal match(
                                    case Dog d: "woof... " + d.BarkLikeCrazy()
                                    case Cat c: "meow"
                                    case * : "I'm mute.."
                              )
                              select new { Type = animal, Sound = sound };

        foreach (var animal in organizedAnimals)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{animal.Type.ToString()} - {animal.Sound}");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about VS "15" Preview 3? Or VS 2015 Update 3? It's confusing, but those two are entirely separate. Also, I don't think `match` is going to be in C# 7.0.

Comment: This is part of the help shows: Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 15 Preview 3
Version 15.0.25428.1 PREVIEW
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01055

Installed Version: Enterprise

Architecture and Modeling Tools   00369-50000-00000-AA450
Microsoft Architecture and Modeling Tools

Visual C# 15 Preview 3   00369-50000-00000-AA450
Microsoft Visual C# 15 Preview 3

Visual C++ 15 Preview 3   00369-50000-00000-AA450
Microsoft Visual C++ 15 Preview 3

Comment: It is a shame if match doesn't make it. It has been in F# for years.

Comment: See [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0//) on what's in VS15 (btw update 4). Some of the C#7 features are still restricted.

Answer (score 1):

**Change your `match` keyword to a `switch`.**

```
var organizedAnimals = from animal in animals
                       let sound = animal switch(
                            case Dog d: "woof... " + d.BarkLikeCrazy()
                            case Cat c: "meow"
                            case * : "I'm mute.."
                      )
                      select new { Type = animal, Sound = sound };
```

You can read about the evolution of this in the [discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/5154) (prior to being merged to the Pattern Matching spec).

Here's an example of it from the [GitHub feature discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/future/docs/features/patterns.md):

```
var areas =
    from primitive in primitives
    let area = primitive switch (
        case Line l: 0,
        case Rectangle r: r.Width * r.Height,
        case Circle c: Math.PI * c.Radius * c.Radius,
        case *: throw new ApplicationException()
    )
    select new { Primitive = primitive, Area = area };
```

Comment: I get all sort of errors, the first being on the match "The query body must end with a select clause or a group clause". I do have  (underscoreunderscore) __DEMO__,__DEMO_EXPERIMENTAL__ defined for the project.

Comment: I also noticed that you linked to Roslyn. Not sure what the relation of Roslyn is to 2015 Enterprise Preview 3.

Comment: You're looking for new C#7 features - Roslyn is the C# compiler. Sounds like you need to go through the steps to use C#7 features in your project.  See: http://www.strathweb.com/2016/03/enabling-c-7-features-in-visual-studio-15-preview/

Comment: See the post two above yours. This isn't working. I can't even tell what link to go to download Roslyn. I went here https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs , but this VS2015 community also has the same problem.

Comment: I downloaded VS2015 Enterprise that contains an experimental version of VS. This one still does not allow the code above neither match nor switch, but it does hint that new features of the C# language are slowly dripping into it.

Comment: My apologies, I misread your first comment to mean the inverse. :/ I'll go poke around and see if I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I make this program work under C#7?

You don't. Expression-based pattern matching is not available in the current preview of C# 7.0 and is not planned for the final version of C# 7.0.

[The form that's currently planned for "C# 7.0 + 1"](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/features/patterns/docs/features/patterns.md#match-expression) looks like this:

```
var organizedAnimals = from animal in animals
                       let sound = animal switch (
                            case Dog d: "woof... " + d.BarkLikeCrazy(),
                            case Cat c: "meow",
                            case *: "I'm mute.."
                        )
                        select new { Type = animal, Sound = sound };
```

Comment: I just updated to the latest c# preview (17?) and this still does not work.

Comment: @Ivan VS 2017 RC still contains only C# 7.0. There is currently no version of VS or the C# compiler where this would work.